# "ng lint" quiet option?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

How can I run `ng lint` without showing warnings? TSLint CLI provides a --quiet flag, but there doesn't appear to be one for Angular or a way to pass through CLI flags. I still want warnings in my tsconfig so they show up in the editor, but sometimes I only want a list of errors.

Answer (score 11):

Just run `ng lint --quiet` and only 'error' messages will be shown.

Comment: this is/should be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Widnows solution:

You can use findstr which Searches for patterns of text. The parameter `/v` prints only lines that don't contain a match.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr

```
ng lint [PROJECT NAME] | findstr /v "WARNING: .*"
```

You can omit [Project Name] if you want to run everything in the directory

```
ng lint | findstr /v "WARNING: .*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are asking, but if you add this line:

```
"defaultSeverity": "warning",
```

To your `tslint.json` file, you will get warnings instead of errors when you run `ng lint`.

My `tslint.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "warning",
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    ...
```

Comment: I think he wants to only show the errors and suppress the warnings.

Comment: Correct, I want warnings and errors to both appear in intellisense, but when I run the `ng lint` command, I would like for it to run only reporting the errors.

Comment: Also looking for answer